# Ionic view does not route to correct view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tabs, ionic-framework

For some reason one of my tabs(the chat tab) doesn't work.  All the other tabs work i'm not sure why the chat tab doesn't work.  As you can see from my plunker the chats tab is just blank while the other tabs show content.  In my actual app the title bar shows but has the text of the previous tab.

So heres my plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/k4SknwdMDM2TWJMuRdXj?p=preview

Heres some code:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title></title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.11/css/ionic.min.css">

  <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.11/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>

  <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
  <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

  <!-- Firebase -->
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js"></script>
  <!-- AngularFire -->
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.1.3/angularfire.min.js"></script>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="controllers.js"></script>
  <script src="services.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="starter">
  <!--
      The nav bar that will be updated as we navigate between views.
    -->
  <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
    <ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-bar>
  <!--
      The views will be rendered in the <ion-nav-view> directive below
      Templates are in the /templates folder (but you could also
      have templates inline in this html file if you'd like).
    -->
  <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>

</html>
```

Chat.html

```
<ion-view view-title="Chats">
  <ion-content>
    asdsadsa
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item class="item-remove-animate item-avatar item-icon-right" ng-repeat="chat in chats" type="item-text-wrap" href="#/tab/chats/{{chat.id}}">
        <img ng-src="chat.closet">
        <h2>{{chat.email}}</h2>
        <p>{{chat.heightFt}}</p>
        <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>

        <ion-option-button class="button-assertive" ng-click="remove(chat)">
          Delete
        </ion-option-button>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

tabs.html:

```
<!--
Create tabs with an icon and label, using the tabs-positive style.
Each tab's child <ion-nav-view> directive will have its own
navigation history that also transitions its views in and out.
-->
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-active-positive">

  <!-- Dashboard Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Status" icon-off="ion-ios-pulse" icon-on="ion-ios-pulse-strong" href="#/tab/dash">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-dash"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <!-- Chats Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Chats" icon-off="ion-ios-chatboxes-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-chatboxes" href="#/tab/chats">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-chats"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <!-- Account Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Account" icon-off="ion-ios-gear-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-gear" href="#/tab/account">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-account"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="Settings" hidden="true">
      <ion-nav-view name="tab-settings"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

app.js

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
// 'starter.services' is found in services.js
// 'starter.controllers' is found in controllers.js
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'firebase', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])



.run(function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, $firebaseObject) {
    $rootScope.ref = new Firebase("https://vivid-fire-3325.firebaseio.com");

    $rootScope.isLoggedIn = false;

  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
  // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
  // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
  // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
  $stateProvider

  // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
    .state('tab', {
    url: '/tab',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
  })

  // Each tab has its own nav history stack:

  .state('tab.dash', {
    url: '/dash',
    views: {
      'tab-dash': {
        templateUrl: 'tab-dash.html',
        controller: 'DashCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('tab.chats', {
      url: '/chats',
      views: {
        'tab-chats': {
          templateUrl: 'tab-chats.html',
          controller: 'ChatsCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tab.chat-detail', {
      url: '/chats/:chatId',
      views: {
        'tab-chats': {
          templateUrl: 'chat-detail.html',
          controller: 'ChatDetailCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

  .state('tab.account', {
    url: '/account',
    views: {
      'tab-account': {
        templateUrl: 'tab-account.html',
        controller: 'AccountCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('tab.settings', {
    url: '/settings',
    views: {
      'tab-settings': {
        templateUrl: 'tab-settings.html',
        controller: 'SettingsCtrl'
      }
    }
  });

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/dash');

});
```

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Named the chat file in the plunker incorrectly.  Changed the name of Chat.html to Chats.html.  It still does not work however, here is the new plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/k4SknwdMDM2TWJMuRdXj?p=preview

Comment: tab-chats.html doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tab activates that means, problem has to do something with your view.
Change `tab-chats.html` to `tab-chat.html`

Comment: I changed the file name from tab-chat to tab-chats.html.  I think this was just a typo when I made the file on plunker as all my code refers to tab-chats.html.  It still does not work however, any ideas?

Comment: Check the console, there is a javascript error. Try removing everything from tab-chats.html and try. Like this http://plnkr.co/edit/CPkki1eKOHPoNHLVuekh?p=preview

Comment: Oh okay I guess it was just the <ion-list> that was calling stuff that didn't exist.  Thanks